# How to use Server Side Event (SSE) with BFF?

Tags: websocket, push-notification

I have a Backend Server which is a typical SpringBoot application. I want to notify the Client when there is a client-specific notifications.
I have set-up BFF layer which is a node-express application.
Any communication between Client and Server is via BFF proxy.

How can we setup Server Side Event (SSE) in this use case?

Also, any other option for Real-time notification system, where we only send data from Server to Client!